# why mailgun sends an email to only authorised recipients?

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I searched for solution in google but unable to find.

In my application when user sign up ,I have to send an activation email to that user. To do that I am using mailgun.

But the problem with that is I need to manually add that user email(eg: gmail) in mailgun authorised recipients list and only then it sends activation email to that person.

But this is not what I want, I need to send an activation link to people when they signup in my app without adding them to mailgun authorised recipients list. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using the free sandbox version?

Comment: Yes. I haven't added my own domain yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you did not add a credit card.

> #### Why is a credit card required to send to non-authorized recipients?
>
> **Accounts without a credit card are restricted to a “trial” mode that only allows messages to be sent to recipients who have been added to the authorized recipient list.**  This restriction helps prevent abuse of the platform.  To remove this restriction, you can add a credit card to your account.  Even after adding a credit card, you will only be charged when your usage exceeds the free allocation.

Source: https://www.mailgun.com/pricing

Comment: Thank you. Just credit card is sufficient to send emails to non-authorized recipients or do we also need to provide our own domain to have this facility?

Comment: I added my credit card details but still I am not getting email for users who are not authorized recipients.

Comment: Looks like with sandbox domain we can only send emails to authorised recipients though we provide credit card information

Comment: See https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#how-do-i-pick-a-domain-name-for-my-mailgun-account

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thanks

Comment: can we remove the debit card after adding it?